# Search for a substring within listed files with spaces from multiple directories in bash

Tags: arrays, string, bash, search, substring

I want to create a script that loops over multiple directories from an array and, if the files there, which are not in the blacklist, are older than a certain time period, remove them. The problem is that any type of string comparison (whether `grep -q` or wildcards) doesn't work when trying to list a directory with files that contain spaces in them (so I change the `$IFS` value to loop through them), making the script unusable. Blacklisted strings can also have spaces in them, of course.

Here's what I wrote so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a dirs=(~/path/to/dir1/* ~/path/to/dir2/*)
declare -a blacklist=("file number 1" "file number 2" "file number 3")


saveifs=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

echo "Starting the autocleaner..."

for dirname in "${dirs[@]}"; do
        for filename in $(ls "$dirname"); do
                for excluded in ${blacklist[@]}; do
                        if [ -e $filename ]; then
                                if echo "$filename" | grep -q "$excluded"; then
                                # if [[ "$filename" == *"$excluded"* ]]; then
                                        :
                                else
                                        if test `find "$filename" -mtime +1`; then
                                                # rm -f $filename
                                                echo "File $filename removed."
                                        else
                                                echo "File $filename is up-to-date and doesn't need to be removed."
                                        fi
                                fi
                        else
                                :
                        fi
                done
        done
done

IFS=$saveifs
```

How can I make the comparison actually work?

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using single square brackets `[ ... ]` for the comparison line? Reading about the difference [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS) between `[ ... ]` and `[[ ... ]]` may help you.